# Logoff and then sleep in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sleep, script

I have a habit to logoff and then sleep the computer in order to eliminate boot time but restart all user programs. I have to click logoff, wait for the login screen and then click sleep. I wonder if there is a way to do both with one click. A script maybe?

Comment: I am not aware of a way to log off and sleep. Like @Jay recommends, you can set a normal Sleep timer (such as 15 minutes) and just Log Off, trusting the timer to put the computer to sleep a little bit later.

Answer (score 2):

Just click on your Windows Start Icon and search "sleep". Click on "Change When Computer Sleeps." You can easily change when your computer automatically go to sleep.